# Grails domain making fields repeatable

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'm a beginner in Grails development. I want to make a new simple MySQL CRUD application which has repeatable fields in it. Now I'm not sure how my domain should look like. Let's say I have 3 fields in my domain:

```
String term
String synonym
String author
```

I want to make author and/or synonym repeatable: is the correct way to proceed to make two new domain classes Synonym and Author and put this in my original domain:

```
static hasMany = [synonym: Synonym]
static hasMany = [author: Author]
```

It seems to me Grails would have a more clever way to do this, but maybe I'm just expecting too much..

Comment: What you do looks correct. Though, not sure what you mean by "repeatable".

Comment: do synonym and author go together?

Comment: With repeatable I mean I need to be able to create records such as: term = donkey, synonym = horse, synonym = ass, author = author1, author = author2, author = author3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you name "repeatable" is commonly called a one-to-many relation. One term has many authors and many synonyms.

So far what you do looks correct.

Though I'd like to suggest to name the `hasMany` declarations in a **plural** form as they are holding multiple `Synonyms`/`Authors`:

```
static hasMany = [synonyms: Synonym]
static hasMany = [authors: Author]
```

As a consequence of the `hasMany` definition you also have to think about the other side of the relationships. An author may also have many terms (many-to-many). For the synonym you have to evaluate if you want to allow to reuse the same Synonym for multiple terms or if it stands for one single term only (one-to-many vs many-to-many).

Comment: ok thanks for the clear answer and for pointing me to the one-to-many relation. Found a tutorial for doing what I want http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/